# selecting data from table based on date 

Tags: sql, mysql

i have database table like this

```
+-------+--------------+----------+
|   id  |    ip        |    date  |
+-------+--------------+----------+
|   505 |192.168.100.1 |2010-04-03|
|   252 |192.168.100.5 |2010-03-03|
|   426 |192.168.100.6 |2010-03-03|
|   201 |192.168.100.7 |2010-04-03|
|   211 |192.168.100.10|2010-04-03|
+-------+--------------+----------+
```

how can i retirive data from this table where month=03 how to write sql to do that .

```
select * from table where month=03
```

something like that .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using mysql, use the MONTH() function I think.

```
select * from table where month(date) = 3
```

Comment: This is the simplest method, but also will not allow indexes to be used, as you're deriving a new value from the table's contents, which is not indexed.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively

```
select * from table where '2010-02-31' < date < '2010-04-01'
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where month(date) = 3
```

If you are searching over 2010-03, it would be recommended to do it this way:

```
select * from table where date >= '2010-03-01' AND date < '2010-04-01'
```

Because this query will use an index if available

Comment: I need last 4 months records means how do i get

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE month(date) = 3
```

OR using the datepart Function:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE datepart(mm, date)=3
```