# Retrive record of all the dates of the given month?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

how to get all the record from Mysql by supplying month in the query?
i am working in php project and i have a mysql table for posts in which all the posts are saved with their dates(not the publish date or post date but any random date).
now i am selecting the month from the front end and querying for the posts for the given month. 
how to retrieve the posts that are in between that month ?

Comment: Just getting data between month without year will yield wrong data !! 2014/03 and 2013/03 - 03 is same for both years. More over post some data and table structure in the question.

Comment: year will be the current year

Comment: What is the format of your date in the SQL table? Is it a numerical unix timestamp? It will help if you could post an example of your code and a small selection of your current table data. An expected output will help you get a more direct answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [selecting data from table based on date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607478/selecting-data-from-table-based-on-date)

Answer (score 0):

You could use MySQL's MONTH() function

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE MONTH( date_col ) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add where condition as

```
WHERE YEAR(col_name_of_date) = 2014 AND MONTH(Date) = 4";
```

or

```
WHERE YEAR(col_name_of_date) = YEAR(now()) AND MONTH(Date) = 4";
```

This will need the column col_name_of_date to be in `DATE` or `DATETIME` type.

Also you should avoid this kind of DATE() function since its a load to the mysql server.

Its better to construct the date parameter on PHP side before u pass them to query. If you
know the moth start and end and can easily construct the start and end date in `Y-m-d` format. For the start date d is always 01 and for the end date its the last day of the month.

Check how the query behaves using DATE() and without date

I have a table users where regdate is not indexed

```
explain select count(*) from users where year(regdate) = year(now()) and month(regdate) = 01 ;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 79309 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
```

As u can see num of rows it may scan is the upper limit of the table.

Now lets add an index

```
mysql> alter table users add index `u_regdate_idx`(`regdate`) ;
Query OK, 79309 rows affected (1.44 sec)
Records: 79309  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Now run the same again

```
mysql> explain select count(*) from users where year(regdate) = year(now()) and month(regdate) = 01 ;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | index | NULL          | u_regdate_idx | 4       | NULL | 79309 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
```

As u can see there is no change in the performance.

Now lets change the query and see

```
mysql> explain select count(*) from users where regdate between '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-31' ;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | range | u_regdate_idx | u_regdate_idx | 4       | NULL |    1 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

Now u can see its far better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MONTHName() function to check the data with the name of month you selected rom front-end.

```
SELECT  * FROM tablename WHERE MONTHNAME(date_column) = "March"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can fire this query
Select * from table where Date =>'$date1' and Date = '$date2'
to find data between any two dates